chart "gitlab/gitlab-runner" not found in https://charts.gitlab.io repository
I encountered an issue when trying to install the gitlab-runner chart using Helm with the following command:
sudo helm install gitlab-runner gitlab/gitlab-runner --namespace gitlab --create-namespace --repo https://charts.gitlab.io
The error message I received is:
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: chart "gitlab/gitlab-runner" not found in https://charts.gitlab.io repository
However, when I run helm repo list, I can see that the gitlab repository is correctly listed:
helm repo list
NAME    URL
jfrog   https://charts.jfrog.io/
gitlab  https://charts.gitlab.io

Despite this, Helm is unable to find the gitlab-runner chart in the repository when using sudo.

Attempts to resolve:
I've confirmed the repository URL is correct.
I've ensured that the Helm chart gitlab/gitlab-runner exists in the gitlab repository.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
I tried running the following command to install the gitlab-runner chart from the GitLab repository:
sudo helm install gitlab-runner gitlab/gitlab-runner --namespace gitlab --create-namespace --repo https://charts.gitlab.io
I also checked that the GitLab repository was correctly added to Helm by running helm repo list, which confirmed that the repository URL was correct. After running the command, I got the following error:
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: chart "gitlab/gitlab-runner" not found in https://charts.gitlab.

I was expecting Helm to find the gitlab/gitlab-runner chart in the GitLab repository and proceed with the installation without errors.

You seem to be merging two way to do helm. Either with adding a repo or directly from a repo.
If you want to just add it using the repo url then dont prefix the chart with a repo name
$ helm install gitlab-runner gitlab-runner --namespace gitlab --create-namespace --repo https://charts.gitlab.io
NAME: gitlab-runner
LAST DEPLOYED: Fri Nov 15 17:56:26 2024
NAMESPACE: gitlab
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
TEST SUITE: None
NOTES:
#############################################################################################
## WARNING: You did not specify an gitlabUrl in your 'helm install' call.                  ##
#############################################################################################

This deployment will be incomplete until you provide the URL that your
GitLab instance is reachable at:

alternatively you can add the repository to helm and then reference if using the repo name
$ helm repo add gitlab https://charts.gitlab.io
"gitlab" has been added to your repositories

$ helm install gitlab-runner gitlab/gitlab-runner --namespace gitlab --create-namespace
NAME: gitlab-runner
LAST DEPLOYED: Fri Nov 15 18:00:32 2024
NAMESPACE: gitlab
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
TEST SUITE: None
NOTES:
#############################################################################################
## WARNING: You did not specify an gitlabUrl in your 'helm install' call.                  ##
#############################################################################################

This deployment will be incomplete until you provide the URL that your
GitLab instance is reachable at:

    helm upgrade gitlab-runner \
        --set gitlabUrl=http://gitlab.your-domain.com,runnerRegistrationToken=your-registration-token \
        gitlab/gitlab-runner

Runner namespace "gitlab" was found in runners.config template.

